# Can I delay the $200 to avoid paying some of my taxes?

Tags: monopoly

Say you pass go in Monopoly and you land on a property stating to pay 10% of your entire bank. Is it against the rules to not pick up the $200 from passing go until after you pay the 10%?

Comment: I’m not sure if editing out any mention of cheating is going too far. It might have just been an issue of terminology; but the question was originally asking if something was cheating or not; not only what the rules are. If we leave the question as-is; my answer needs to be edited as well.

Comment: In some ways, I guess it's also up to you, as the 10% of your entire bank is a house rule (or some esoteric variant I'm not aware of), so it would be up to you how you decide to implement it.

Comment: @MattTaylor No, 10% is specifically an option in the rules, and printed on the Income Tax space itself...

Comment: https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/thmb/Yl7SYVeFs_wuxhAtYnmAGI_mBtg=/450x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/8266555568_218538bcb4_z-59642e953df78cdc68c06a61.jpg

Comment: @GendoIkari since which version? That may well be a US-only thing, as I've never seen a UK Monopoly board with that alternate, it's always just pay £200

Comment: @MattTaylor It appears that the UK edition does not have the 10%... It is part of the original rules, but in 2008 the US editions started leaving it out as well. http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Income_Tax

Answer (score 10):

You will get your $200 before paying the tax.

From the [the rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf):

> Each time a player's token lands on **or passes over** GO, whether by throwing the dice or drawing a card, the Banker pays himther a $200 salary.

So the $200 comes as a result of passing over Go, technically you would have that money before you even get to your final landing space of Income Tax.

Note that this is not really a question of cheating. Generally cheating means to intentionally break the rules to gain an advantage. If someone thought that you were not supposed to get the $200 until after you paid the tax, they would be playing incorrectly. But it would only be cheating if other payers were playing correctly and a player purposely paid too little tax.

Comment: I think your answer is still good even though any mention of cheating has been edited out of the question.

Comment: Indeed the "GO" space says, "Collect 200 *as you pass*" i.e. not "After you pass" or anything else, implying you take your money as you pass that space and before you reach the tax space.